# php if else & URL vars

Tags: php

URL

> x.php?foo=100

x.php

```
$x = $_GET['foo'];

if ($x = 100) {
   echo "yeah";    
}else{
   echo "no";
}
```

My code doesnt work, where is error?

Comment: @Jleagle I assume because the question gets asked like ten times a day. I must say this is one of the better ones though.

Comment: Ilya, for long term, you should read this: [PHP Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a single equal mark (`=`) instead of two in the IF statement (`if ($x = 100) {`).

A single equal mark will set the value 100 into $x, and then evaluate the IF statement with it - which evaluates to true in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($x == "100")
```

or

```
if (intval($x) === 100)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($x = 100) {
```

sets $x to 100 and evaluates the result. You want:

```
if ($x == '100') {
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are using an assignment statement instead of checking for equality in the line:
if ($x = 100)
Try
if ($x == 100)
instead.

Answer (score 1):

you are not comparing value of x, you are saying that x is equal to 100

try

if($x == 100) { echo "yeah"; }

Answer (score 1):

first check with `isset($_REQUEST['foo'])` or `isset($_GET['foo'])`